# Two checkboxes checked on one click in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, redux, react-redux

I have one component (Fuel) which I use in two other components (Search and SmallFilters) :

Search component is as follows :

```
class search extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const language = this.props.language.default.portal;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="searchTitle"><FontAwesome name="search" className="portalFaIcon"/>  {language.search}</div>
                <Fuel language={language} actionFilters={this.props.actionFilters} filters={this.props.filters}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return {
        favorites: state.favorites,
        filters: state.filters,
        carsToShow: state.carsToShow
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        actionFilters: bindActionCreators(filterActions, dispatch),
        actionCarsToShow: bindActionCreators(actionCarsToShow, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(search);
```

The SmallFilters is as follows :

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className="filters noPadding col-xl-8 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                <Fuel recap={true} title={_.startCase(_.toLower(filter_names.fuel))} {...this.props}/>
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The Fuel component is as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import { filter_names } from './filterActions';

export default class fuel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = this.getFilterValues()
    }

    emptyValues(){
        return {
            checkboxDiesel: false,
            checkboxBenzine: false
        }
    }

    handleFilter(){
        if(this.state.checkboxDiesel || this.state.checkboxBenzine){
            this.props.actionFilters.addFuelFilter(this.state);
        }else{
            this.props.actionFilters.removeFuelFilter();
        }
    }

    handleDiesel(event){
        const checkbox = event.target.checked;
        this.setState({checkboxDiesel: checkbox, checkboxBenzine: this.state.checkboxBenzine}, () => this.handleFilter());
    }

    handleBenzine(event){
        const checkbox = event.target.checked;
        this.setState({checkboxBenzine: checkbox, checkboxDiesel: this.state.checkboxDiesel}, () => this.handleFilter());
    }

    deActivate(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState(this.emptyValues(), () => this.handleFilter());
    }

    getFilterValues(){
        debugger;
        if(!this.props.filters.some(i => i.name === filter_names.fuel)){
            return this.emptyValues();
        }

        return {
            checkboxDiesel: this.props.filters.filter(f => f.name === filter_names.fuel).map(i => i.values.map(v => v.checkboxDiesel)),
            checkboxBenzine: this.props.filters.filter(f => f.name === filter_names.fuel).map(i => i.values.map(v => v.checkboxBenzine))
        };

        /*let values = {};
        this.props.filters.filter(f => {
            if(f.name == filter_names.fuel){
                values.checkboxDiesel = f.values[0].checkboxDiesel;
                values.checkboxBenzine = f.values[0].checkboxBenzine;
            }
        });
        return values;*/
    }

    renderSmall() {
        let diesel = this.getFilterValues().checkboxDiesel ? "Diesel" : "";
        let benzine = this.getFilterValues().checkboxBenzine ? "Benzine" : "";
        return (
            <div className="filter">
                {this.props.title} <Link to="" onClick={this.deActivate.bind(this)}><FontAwesome name="times" className="portalFaRedIcon"/></Link>
                <div className="filterValues">{diesel} {benzine}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const language = this.props.language;

        if(this.props.recap) return this.renderSmall();
        console.log(this.props.filters);

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="priceTitle" style={{padding: '5px 0'}}>{language.fuel}</div>
                <div className="transmissionValues">
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleDiesel.bind(this)} checked={this.getFilterValues().checkboxDiesel}/> <span>Diesel</span>
                </div>
                <div className="transmissionValues">
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleBenzine.bind(this)} checked={this.getFilterValues().checkboxBenzine}/> <span>Benzine</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I click on one of those checkboxes, both are checked. And If I click on the same checkbox both are unchecked. But if I click on the other one nothing happends.

This.props.filters comes from redux store and it's something like this if one of those checkboxes is checked :

```
[{name: "FUEL", values: [{checkboxDiesel: true, checkboxBenzine: false}]}]
```

Any advice?

Comment: Looks like you wrote too much code for so simple functions, readability of the code is also very hard. note you should always use camel cases too, not fuel but Fuel etc..

Comment: @IlanHasanov It's it simple when you use states. But when you have two component which are using it, and you need to use redux store, then it can't be  written so simple.

Answer (score 0):

By a long shot, I think you should just use `this.state` to update your input's value. Read [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) from the docs.

```
render() {
    const language = this.props.language;

    if(this.props.recap) return this.renderSmall();
    console.log(this.props.filters);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="priceTitle" style={{padding: '5px 0'}}>{language.fuel}</div>
            <div className="transmissionValues">
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleDiesel.bind(this)} checked={this.state.checkboxDiesel}/> <span>Diesel</span>
            </div>
            <div className="transmissionValues">
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleBenzine.bind(this)} checked={this.state.checkboxBenzine}/> <span>Benzine</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If there are any side-effects of this action, you can do that in `handleDiesel` or `handleBenzine` methods. Let me know if it works. Meanwhile, I'll try to understand more from your code.

Comment: If I change it to this.state.checkboxDiesel and this.state.checkboxBenzine, then they can be separately checked, but then deactivate function doesn't deactivate them.

Comment: @Boky What do you want `deActivate` to do? Does it disable the checkboxes or does it just uncheck the checkboxes?

Comment: It uncheck them and removes the filter with name FUEL ( `[{name: "FUEL", values: [{checkboxDiesel: true, checkboxBenzine: false}]}]` ) from the redux store.

Comment: @Boky I don't see how is it not working. After the proposed tweak, I don't understand which part is breaking your flow. Can you check if there are any logical errors in your code? I just replaced `getFilterValues()` with `this.state.checkboxDiesel` and `this.state.checkboxBenzine`. `deActivate` does not even come in the picture.

Comment: It does not come in the picture when it's called from Search component but deActivate is triggered when this component is called by smallFilters component.

Comment: @Boky Hmm.. I'm not sure, what's breaking your code. Anyways, you need to review your code. Also, don't call any methods in `checked` prop to your checkbox. I think it's an anti-pattern to React's declarative model. I think you should keep `checked={this.state.checkboxDiesel}` and modify other things accordingly.